# $(this). methods (js or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at some js/jquery code and I saw this line here:
`$(this).`

**How can one find out what methods to call on this thing.** Is there something similar to javadocs for js?

Is this code in js or is it jquery?

Note: this might be of relevance to those who reply, I write backend code and never done front end (not more than simple html)

Comment: `$` is probably jQuery and the API reference is here: http://api.jquery.com/. But it could also be Prototype: http://www.prototypejs.org/.

Comment: @FelixKling you're my hero :) It's exactly what I needed. The list of all methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` method is just an alias for the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) method. It will wrap the element (or object) and expose the methods available to the framework. Many other javascript libraries use `$` as an alias as well.

Answer (score 1):

In that case `this` refers to a DOM element, and `$(this)` refers to that element turned into a jQuery set.

It then has all the usual jQuery functions

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery

$(this) is used to when you want to operate on the selected selector

e.g.

If you want to get the value of the text box element with class "email" and this is how the code can be written

```
$('email').blur(function(){
  var email = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the limited info you provided, this could be anything. I would put a debug point on `$(this).` and create a watch on this to see what it is and what methods it exposes. Firebug is really good at showing this.